# How to set multiple Delims

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on writing a script that will create folders based on parts of file names.  The problem is the Delim's are both the same.  File names look like this: "Bacon-HunterBacon-00002"  I am looking at using the first and second tokens to be the folder name.  So the folder would be named Bacon-HunterBacon

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%A in (*.cr2 *.jpg) do (
   echo file found  %%A


   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB


   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC


   for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=-" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!

   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )

   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)`"tokens=1,2* delims=-" %%D in ...`, the first token is assigned to `%%D`, the second one to `%%E` and the rest (`*`) to `%%F` (but which you do not use), so you should do `set folname=%%D-%%E` to get the desired folder name in variable `folname`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%A in ("*-*-*.cr2" "*-*-*.jpg") do (
    echo file found  %%A

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%D in ("%%~nA") do set "folname=%%D-%%E"
    echo folder name !folname!

    if not exist "!folname!" (
        echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
        md "!folname!"
    ) else (
        echo Folder !folname! exists
    )

    echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
    move "%%~A" "!folname!"
)

endlocal
echo Finished
```

The loops `for /f "delims=" %%B` and `for /f "delims=" %%C` are useless, you could use `%%~nA` and `%%~xA` directly to get the values `fname` and `fextn`, respectively. But you do not need these interim variables at all, therefore I removed them.

And you should use the quoted `set` syntax like `set "folname=%%D-%%E"` in general.

I also changed the file masks to not match files that contain less than two hyphens (`-`).

---

Actually you do not even need the interim variable `folname` when you use the tokens `%%D` and `%%E` immediately. So you do no longer need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) any more:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal

for %%A in ("*-*-*.cr2" "*-*-*.jpg") do (
    echo file found  %%A

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
        echo folder name %%D-%%E

        if not exist "%%D-%%E" (
            echo Folder %%D-%%E does not exist, creating
            md "%%D-%%E"
        ) else (
            echo Folder %%D-%%E exists
        )

        echo Moving file %%A to folder %%D-%%E
        move "%%~A" "%%D-%%E"
    )
)

endlocal
echo Finished
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that code still only uses Token 1 and creates folders using the first token, (Bacon).  I am a bit over my head here, so I appreciate all of you help.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned the issue in the text but forgot to correct the code then; fixed now...

Comment: @JoeyFreeman, you're welcome! If an answer completely satisfies you consider to accept it; please read this as for why this is important: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Anyway, you can wait a bit to get even a better answer, of course...

Comment: No Problem, is there a way to make it save the space.  I have file names set up like: Shiraz-Rider 49-002365 .  And when the folder is created it creates it as Rider49 without a space.  I would like it to be Rider 49.  Is that possible?  Thanks

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce that, when I test the code (both approaches), the spaces are preserved as expected; have you copied the most recent version of the script here?

Comment: You're right, Sorry.  It is another program I am using.  Thanks again!